# .NET consume php web service

Tags: c#, php, soap

I have php web service. and can consume it from php client.

But problem  occurs  when i try call from c# win app.

Do you have any ideas..

Problem is it returns null, also i cannot see it from object browser

My wsdl file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:ns1="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:ns0="http://1sunucu.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" targetNamespace="http://1sunucu.com"> 
  <wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema xmlns:ns="http://1sunucu.com" xmlns:ns1="http://1sunucu.com/xsd" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://HighSchool.edu">
      <xs:element name="ExamResult">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="kullaniciKod" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="sifre" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="ExamResultResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="result" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="ExamResultRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns0:ExamResult"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="ExamResultResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns0:ExamResultResponse"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="ExamResultPortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="ExamResult">
      <wsdl:input message="ns0:ExamResultRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:ExamResult"/>
      <wsdl:output message="ns0:ExamResultResponse" wsaw:Action="urn:ExamResultResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="ExamResultSOAP12Binding" type="ns0:ExamResultPortType">
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="ExamResult">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="urn:ExamResult" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="ExamResult">
    <wsdl:port name="ExamResultSOAP12port_http" binding="ns0:ExamResultSOAP12Binding">
      <soap12:address location="http://localhost/ws/soap-server.php"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [SoapUi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/). i have solved the problem...There was a response error in php server